# VSC will not open any browser

Tags: browser, plugins

I have installed VSC globally, and then for users; but no browsers work. I have run VSC in admin mode but no browsers work. VSC will not open any browser! No plugins like 'Open IN Browser' will open any browser! The same error message for all configurations: 'Open browser failed!! Please check if you have installed the browser chrome (current selection) correctly!' I have spent 2 days surfing the net for answers but all given solutions have no effect on VSC. I really like VSC but if I cannot get this to work today I got to move on. Work is piling up, lol...live long and prosper!
Below is the info from VSC:

Version: 1.44.2 (user setup)
Commit: ff915844119ce9485abfe8aa9076ec76b5300ddd
Date: 2020-04-16T16:36:23.138Z
Electron: 7.1.11
Chrome: 78.0.3904.130
Node.js: 12.8.1
V8: 7.8.279.23-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.18363

Comment: By VSC do you mean Visual Studio Code?

Comment: Hi Dan: yes indeed, VSC is Visual Studio Code. I went the extra length and dual booted into Ubuntu 20.04 to test the new VSC on Linux. Well, guess what? Yes, you are right...the same problem. I now knew with certainty that the plugin called 'Open in Browser' was 'not fully developed' or, at least, part of the broken code chain. Finally...ugh...I simply looked for an earlier version and voila, everything is back to a working state. Oh my...what a cost of time...live long & prosper...Derek